# Why does my pre-rendered react website not work with Javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I have created, using create-react-app, [this website](https://alexandermorton.co.uk)

I use react snapshot to pre-render each route which I serve to the browser. I did this for web crawlers and so the initial render is quicker.

I first test this with postman to check that each route actually renders the content. The HTML for each route contains the content I want.

However, when I test this with google dev tools and disable Javascript the root route renders correctly but all the others only render the header, background picture and the footer. **I have no idea why this is**. I see, using google console fetch and render, that google crawler also don't see these pages correctly.

***Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?***

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: did you checked with react extension for web developer tool?

Comment: No. I've never really used it. Would would it tell me?

Comment: Please try to install google chrome react extension it will help to debug your script

Comment: I don't see why. The script should not be running in the first place?